# Software for reading 2 pages of PDF side by side

Tags: windows, pdf, web-browser

I'm not sure if this is the correct place to ask this kind of questions (and if anyone know the right place, he can let me know). Anyway I'm asking here because maybe somebody has (had? hopefully) my same problem. I'm struggling reading papers or doing research due to the vertical height of my screen. as you can see from the following image:

[image: []]

The pdf file is not even nearly fitting the screen, so I have to scroll back and forth through the page. which is painful! I'm wondering if exists a method to get the same pdf (or in general the same web browser instance!) but split in a side-by-side manner in a way I have on left side of the screen the upper half of the pdf's page, and on the right side the remaining part. In this way I can fully take advantage of the horizontal width of my screen and I can finally have the entirety of a pdf's page on the very same display! But.. let's see the image below:

[image]

These are two instances of the same pdf file (yuppie!) BUT I have to scroll each one independently from the other. this is not what I meant! The thing that I'm in searching for is a way to scroll them simultaneously, in a way that the software gives me an arbitrary part of pdf's page on the left and the very continuation of it on the right and this in every moment.

---

[**NOTE**]: it would be great if such a thing could happen for every app in the system. or at least for the web browser. In this way I could have a part of (for example) Wikipedia's page on the left, and *its continuation* on the right. At every times. For every 'scrolling actions' I can do.

I'm (unfortunately) haven't done anything yet of myself. I was expecting some good advice on pdf reader software and/or web extensions.

Comment: My solution is to use more than one screen and have one set as portrait mode.  This is the one I use for pdfs.

Comment: @RohitGupta i see that it could be a solution, but maybe i wasn't clear about my needs.. i need it for a laptop, which i have to bring it with me in university for lessons or studying and i simply can't bring an entire monitor with me....

Comment: @RohitGupta i was thinking about something to split my physical monitor into two virtual monitor.. so i can 'extend' the contents of the left screen to the right one.. do you think it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any PDF reader with that capability. **BUT** - I had a thought, tried it and it does what you describe. It's unconventional, are you ready? Assuming you have a relatively recent copy of MS Word (desktop) available...

Open the PDF through the Word file menu (ignore the conversion warning). Then repeat that. You should now have two separate Word instances with the same PDF file.

- In the Word *View* menu, select *View Side by Side*
- The two Word instances should be next to each other and both should show the same page.
- In the *View* menu, **de**select/**de**activate *Synchronous Scrolling*
- Scroll the "right" page about halfway down, approximately in line with the middle of the "left" page
- In the *View* menu, **re**select/**re**activate *Synchronous Scrolling*

Now, when you read on the "right" side and scroll forward, the "left" page will follow in sync, so that you should always have the whole page visible across botch instances. Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, but maybe it is not what i was looking for.. i mean.. the pdfs i usually read are scientific papers with many formulae, and the word conversion makes literal disasters with formatting.. so it is not a viable option for me.. unless, you know how to prevent the changes to formatting.. thanks in advice

Comment: Your sample PDF images show only text with regular formattig. Perhaps you could provide a link to a proper sample, like one of the scientific papers you are referring to? Find one that's really complex - lots of formulae, tables, graphics - you know, the works. Then let's see.